# Multiple counter from previous lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here I have two piece of codes that I am trying to merge them together, In the first I have a list of letter from which two letters are being chosen randomly and added to the former list:

```
import random

def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newList = aList[:]
for _ in range(2):
    print(newList)
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
print(newList)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ['A', 'C']]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ['A', 'C'], ['D', ['A', 'C']]]
```

Now I want to count each letters in each lists, so I did:

```
import collections
l1 = newList

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c) for c in d] for i in b]
for _ in range(2):
    new_counts = collections.Counter(flatten(l1))
print(new_counts)
```

Which I get:

```
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'B': 1})
```

Which shows the number of elements only in the last list. I wonder how one can count the letter for all lists for example to get something like:

```
Counter({'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'B': 1})
Counter({'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'B': 1})
```

and etc.

Comment: Could you properly indent the code? As it is now, it won't run.

Comment: Anyway, your assignment `newList = randMerge(newList,num)` updates the value inside newList at every iteration. Previous values of newList are not kept in memory. To do what you want, you should either move the counter inside the first `for` loop or assign each list to a separate variable.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi Done the indentation:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put newList obtained in the first loop to a list and iterate through that in the second like,

```
import random

def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newLists = []
newList=aList[:]
for _ in range(2):
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
    print(newList)
    newLists.append(newList)

import collections

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c) for c in d] for i in b]
for newList in newLists:
    new_counts = collections.Counter(flatten(newList))
    print(new_counts)
```

Or you can use a single loop like below.

```
import random

def randMerge(l:list, count:int) -> list:
    return l + [random.sample(l,k=count)]

import collections

def flatten(d):
    return [i for b in [[c] if not isinstance(c, list) else flatten(c) for c in d] for i in b]

num = 2
aList = ['A','B','C','D']
newList = aList[:]
for _ in range(2):
    newList = randMerge(newList,num)
    print(newList)
    new_counts = collections.Counter(flatten(newList))
    print(new_counts)
```

Comment: is it possible to make a histogram of each counter and show them in one plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` for a lazy option.

This would be more efficient than creating a new flattened list from a nested list.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

for newList in newLists:
    new_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(newList))
    print(new_counts)
```